# Need an array index/match formula for multiple duplicate results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

Here is the effect that I am attempting to achieve, in Column C:

[image]

I am trying to make Column C "detect" which entries from D/E are present in A/B. I think one of the problems is that I am not allowed to sort columns A/B other than how it is already sorted as present.

I cannot think of a way to use arrays/index-matching to make a formula that goes down Column C and checks every single entry, while at the same time checking for duplicate entries between other entries as it goes down.

I tried looking up instructions on the Microsoft website and Google regarding duplicate entries using the `SMALL` and `LARGE` functions, but I think they only work if the duplicate entries you are checking are in sequential order. In my list, they are skipping throughout the list.

It would seem like a lot of resources for a formula to keep track of the duplicates, so is there another way to make a formula that checks the entirety of the list every time until it finds a matching entry (although this might take even more resources)? For example, for Rows 10-12, it will check for the number '6' in the 'A' column (rows 6-8 in D), find the first entry at A10, check if B10 matches E6, and in this case, done. Then, check B11 to E6, doesn't match, so check B11 to E7, and in this case it matches, but if it didn't, it would keep going until it reached the end of the list where there exist no more '6' in column D.

I am not sure if I explained my thoughts clearly. Please ask for any clarification necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Could you write, what is criteria for the list  in column D & E ? Since you have skip few of them. Like 1-550, not included 3, 4 and 7 !!

Comment: @RajeshS There is no criteria. It is random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this arrary formula in C1:`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1&B1,$D$1:$D$10&$E$1:$E$10,)),"","YES")`

Enter this formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image]